when using a queue and threads to perform work im find i must use a slight sleep(0.0001) in my main loop in order to process a cmd for each ip
I have a threaded / queue ssh program that iterates over an ip/hostname list and executes a list of commands against each ip/hostname.  I find that if I remove the sleep(0.0001) from the main thread of execution I get commands being repeated for the same host.  However, adding the sleep appears to put a pause long enough to process each unique command for each host.
My expected result would be for each of the unique commands they get run for each ip as such
Thread mpawd1: Running cat /etc/redhat-release to mpawd1
Thread mpawd1: Running uptime to mpawd1
Thread mpawd1: Running "ps -ef |grep java |wc -l" to mpawd1
Thread mpawd1: Running date to mpawd1

When sleep is removed it will repeat some commands against the same ip instead of executing each unique command against the same host.  Like this
Thread mpawd1: Running cat /etc/redhat-release to mpawd1
Thread mpawd1: Running cat /etc/redhat-release to mpawd1
Thread mpawd1: Running "ps -ef |grep java |wc -l" to mpawd1
Thread mpawd1: Running date to mpawd1

This is my config.ini
[MACHINES]
mpawd1=mpawd1
mpawqa=mpawqa
mpawq1=mpawq1
mpawqa3=mpawqa3

[COMMANDS]
cmd1=cat /etc/redhat-release
cmd2=uptime
cmd3="ps -ef |grep java |wc -l"
cmd4=date


#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
from subprocess import PIPE
import configparser
from configparser import ConfigParser
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time
from time import sleep
"""
A threaded ssh based command dispatch system

"""
start = time.time()
queue = Queue()

def readConfig(file="config.ini"):
    """Extract IP addresses and CMDS from config file and returns tuple"""
    ips = []
    cmds = []
    Config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    Config.read(file)
    machines = Config.items("MACHINES")
    commands = Config.items("COMMANDS")
    for ip in machines:
        ips.append(ip[1])
    for cmd in commands:
        cmds.append(cmd[1])
    return ips, cmds

def launcher(i,q, cmd):
    """Spawns command in a thread to an ip"""
    results = []
    while True:
        ip = q.get()
        print ("Thread %s: Running %s to %s\n" % (i, cmd, ip))
        subprocess.check_output("ssh xxxx@%s %s" % (ip, cmd), stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True, shell=True)
        q.task_done()

#grab ips and cmds from config
ips, cmds = readConfig()


#Determine Number of threads to use, but max out at 25
if len(ips) < 25:
    num_threads = len(ips)
else:
    num_threads = 25

#Start thread pool
for i in ips:
    for cmd in cmds:
        #print("cmd %s" % cmd)
        worker = Thread(target=launcher, args=(i, queue,cmd))
        worker.daemon = True
        worker.start()

print ("Main Thread Waiting")
for ip in ips:
    for cmd in cmds:
            sleep(0.0001)
            queue.put(ip)
queue.join()
end = time.time()
print ("Dispatch Completed in %s seconds" % float(end - start))


Aside: why queue the same ip for each cmd - couldn't you just iterate over the cmds for each ip that you dequeue?

Why do you even put the IPs in a queue if you are already passing them as arguments to the threads?

Thanks for both of your input.  I'm a beginner in the python lang but have been working with threading, queues etc in other langs.  I inherited someone else's script mess and trying to work through things.  I went with removing the queueing altogether for this to make things work.  Im still curious why a sleep in the queue method causes the desired outcome as well.

using the same queue for all threads doesn't seem good idea because one thread can get all values from queue and other threads will have no data.

shorter num_threads = min(25, len(ips))
